# NSComparisonResult search part of a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using NSComparisonResult with my SearchController:

```
for (Annotation *ano in listContent) {
        NSComparisonResult result = [ano.title compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchText length])];
        if (result == NSOrderedSame) {
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:ano];
        }
    }
```

If I search for a string it will only find the result if it starts with that string.

Record is "**My Art Gallery**"

- Search for "My Art Gallery" <---
  Found
- Search for "My " <--- Found
- Search for "Art" <--- Not Found
- Search for "Gallery" <--- Not found

How can I change my code so that I can find parts of the string as I showed above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up using NSRange which allowed me to basically search for a substring:

```
for (Annotation *ano in listContent) {

        NSRange range = [ano.title rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
            [self.filteredListContent addObject:ano];
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 6):

There is a straight forward way to do a substring check:

```
NSComparisonResult result1 = [dummyString compare:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch) range:[dummyString rangeOfString:searchText options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)]];
if (result1 == NSOrderedSame)
{
 [self.filteredListContent addObject:dummyString];  // this can vary drastically 
}
```

NOTE: I am using this with a `UISearchDisplayController` and this worked perfectly for me.

Hope this helps you in future.

Thanks to [this post](http://meekismurder.com/blog/?p=40) (UPDATE: This link doesn't work anymore.)